# How to connect to unix via java without passing user name and password

Tags: java, unix

How to connect to a remote unix host from java without passing username and password.

The below code is what I am using

```
   package testing;     

    import java.io.InputStream;

    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            execute();
        }

            public static void execute() {
                    try {
                        JSch jsch = new JSch();

                        String user = "xxxx";
                        String host = "xxxxxx";
                        int port = 22;
                        String privateKey = "xxxxxxxxx";

                        jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
                        System.out.println("identity added ");

                        Session session = jsch.getSession("nudayaku","cloudgw-dev-01" );
                        System.out.println("session created.");
                        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
                        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();    
                        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");      
                        session.setConfig(config);  
                        session.connect();
                        System.out.println("session connected.....");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e);
                    }
                }
    }
```

Please find the below error.

stack trace error

```
com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
     com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
     testing.Test.execute(Test.java:39)
     testing.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Comment: So you have code.  What is your actual problem?  Is it working?  How is it not working?  Do you not know how to use it?

Comment: Hi Stephen,I am using this code but getting the below error

Comment: identity added 
session created.
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

Comment: Add the details to the Question please.

Comment: updated the same in question

Comment: I think you will need the username, even if you use public key auth.

Comment: Can you also change the code to print the stacktrace and include that in the question.  (I want to confirm the statement where the exception is being thrown.)

Comment: updated in casenotes

Answer (score 1):

Based on the evidence so far, the most likely causes are (IMO):

1. You are using the wrong host, and the account doesn't exist on that host.
2. You are using the wrong user name for the remote account
3. You are using a private key that doesn't match one of the public keys recorded for the remote account
4. The remote server is not configured to accept PublicKey auth.
5. The remote account's `~/.ssh` directory is not configured correctly.  A common problem is for either the `~/.ssh` directory or the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to be too open.

I think that we can eliminate problems with the private key file.  I think that would give you a different exception.

---

If none of the above is the cause, then you need to turn on JSch logging at debug level to get more insights as to what is going wroing.  Unfortunately, JSch doesn't use a logging framework by default, but there is an example in the JSch examples page that gives code that you can borrow:

- http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html

Finally, if client-side logging doesn't help, see if you can (temporarily) turn on debugging for `sshd` on the remote server side.  (Be aware that `sshd` is a security / privacy concern.  Sensitive information about *all* SSH connections will be logged.)

---

This is not the problem, but the following code looks a bit strange:

```
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();    
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");      
session.setConfig(config);
```

Why don't you write the last 3 statements as follows?

```
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
```